# igraph (R) How to create correlation network with only strong r values

Tags: r, correlation, igraph

I am trying to figure out how to use graph.adjacency to create a graph using a correlation matrix (values -1 to 1), but only having the most strongly correlated edges included in the graph file, ie <-.8 or >.8

Here is the code that successfully gives me the network with the full data set:

```
corrdata<-read.csv("spearmancorr.csv",header=FALSE)
cor_mat<-as.matrix(corrdata)
diag(cor_mat)<-0
graph<-graph.adjacency(cor_mat,weighted=TRUE,mode="lower")
```

I tried using delete.edges to reduce the network to at least >.8 to test it out, but the resulting file still shows edge weights below 0.8

```
graph.copy <- delete.edges(graph, which(E(graph)$weight !<0.8)-1)
write.graph(graph.copy, file="gsig80.graphml", format="graphml")
```

Any advice on how to get the graph file I want?

Comment: Please make a reproducible example including the data, so I can paste your code into my console and run it without error messages.

Comment: I think you'll have to alter the adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delete the edges from the graph if you want to, or delete them from the matrix in the first place. E.g.

```
cor_mat[ cor_mat < .8 ] <- 0
diag(cor_mat) <- 0
graph <- graph.adjacency(cor_mat, weighted=TRUE, mode="lower")
```

Here is how to delete them from the graph, after creating it:

```
graph <- delete.edges(graph, E(graph)[ weight < 0.8 ])
```

Comment: Both those methods appeared to work, based on the reduction in file size. However, when I check the weights using `E(graph)$weights` the edge weights are no longer the r values, but the IDs from Column A of the matrix file.

Comment: I don't understand this, sorry. Some reproducible example would help. Btw. it is `E(graph)$weight`, without the 's'.

Comment: I added a reproducible matrix in the original question, thanks.

Comment: I can't see any matrix there. Also, where is `spearmancorr.csv`? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the poor reproducible example. However, I determined where the problem occurs. I tested your answer with a smaller matrix (10x10) and it worked fine. My real dataset has a matrix of 5395x5395. When using the big matrix 'delete.edges" strips the graph file of all but 2 edges (which is not correct). Is there a code to make this work with bigger files?

Comment: I understand it even less..... so if the matrix is small, the code works, if it is big, then the edge weights are replaced by some row ids of the matrix? Again, please add a reproducible example. It does not have to be small, if you think the problem is that the matrix is big, set the random seed and create a random matrix. That is reproducible.

Comment: For consistency with the OP's question, this should probably have `cor_mat[abs(cor_mat) < .8] <- 0` (and `abs(weight)`).